# Why doesn't mapbox's native extruded 3d buildings have an FK with OSM building/amenity ID

Tags: mapbox, gis, openstreetmap

I am trying to access the [3d buildings](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-buildings/) in gl-js, and was wondering if there is a simple way to make relationship with [building IDs in OSM](https://osmbuildings.org/?lat=52.52111&lon=13.41075&zoom=18.4&tilt=30), like "ID:r7335322" or "building:159958500" since they are effectively tagging the same unique building? This use case MUST have come up already at some point? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes these building footprints are sourced from OSM, but the OSM id is not retained in Mapbox Streets. The Streets tilesets are designed to be as lightweight as possible, so properties which aren't typically used in cartography are not retained.